# how to randomize an integer variable, with odds on certain numbers appearing

Tags: javascript, html, variables, random

To get a random whole number between 0 and 4 inclusive, I use the following code:

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
```

However I want the number 4 to be chosen twice as often as the other numbers. How would I go about doing getting a random number between 0-4 inclusive, but with the number 4 appearing twice as many times as 0-3?

Comment: Do you want 4 to appear twice as often overall, or twice as many times as 0-3 combined?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the easist way is to add the number twice to the array:

```
var nums = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4];
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
var random = nums[index];
```

But for something more generic, you may have a table:

```
var nums = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
var odds = [0.16667, 0.16667, 0.16667, 0.16667, 0.33333];
var r = Math.random();
var i = 0;
while(r > 0)
  r -= odds[i++];
var random = nums[i];
```

Comment: You don't actually use the nums array?

Comment: It should be obvious the random variable returns the index of the nums array?

Comment: You should change the line to: var random = nums[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)]; for clarity

Comment: I wont be happy to define fixed number array, to get random numbers. Take getting twice chances for a number as a concept, as anyway you can't get exactly twice chances of a number, until you start counting their occurrence manually. And if i had to count anyhow, whats the use of randomness ??

Comment: @simplyharsh: I have no idea what you mean

Answer (score 4):

Just do it like this:

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
if (random == 5) random = 4;
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this of any use:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/weighrandom2.shtml

Answer (score 2):

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0 ? Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) : 4
```

Here, 4 has 50% chance coz of first random selector, adding up 20% for second random selector.

Comment: That's not twice as often as the other numbers..?

Answer (score 2):

I like sje397's initial answer with the correction that Paddy is suggesting:

```
var nums = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4];
var random = nums[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)];
```

Answer (score 1):

The technique behind your requirement is to use a Shuffle Bag random generator. More details: http://web.archive.org/web/20111203113141/http://kaioa.com:80/node/53

Comment: +1 Would be nice if there was a `Collections.shuffle` in javascript :)